# Heron's formula to solve a triangle; any faster method?

Tags: triangles

A triangle has an area of $200cm^{2}$. Two sides of this triangle measure 26 and 40 cm respectively. Find the exact value of the third side.

I used Heron's formula to solve this equation, but it involves a long calculation and then the quadratic formula for a final solution. But, somehow I got it wrong along the way and my answer was x= $2\sqrt {431}+40$ . However, the given answer is $2 \sqrt{89}$, and when I use my CAS calculator to solve the question I do get that as my answer. Is there a faster way to solve these kind of questions if I can't use a calculator? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that the area of a triangle is given by $A=\frac{1}{2}ab \sin C$ where $C$ is the angle between the two sides of length $a$ and $b$. You should be able to solve for $\theta$.

Once you do so, you can compute the length of the last side using the Cosine Rule.

Comment: But how would I solve for angle C without a calculator? If $200=26*40*sinC$, then $5/26=sinC$.

Comment: You have $\sin C$, but you do not need $C$ to find $\cos C$. Simply draw up a triangle and use Pythagoras' Theorem from there.

Comment: I think the Pythagorus step should be included in the answer itself, for completeness.